# How to delete a game file?

Tags: pokemon-sword-shield

Okay, so there are currently two accounts in my Switch system, and I wanted to see if the second account (lovingly named as Guest) has a different save file or something. I soon found out that it did; I was sent to the character creation rather than from where I left it off in Account #1.

Anyway, other details aside, I picked the same starter Pokémon again in this second account rather than a different one, so I'm wondering if there's a way to delete Account #2's save file without affecting Account #1's save file (kinda saved already, so... yeah. Also, the 1st account is already at mid-game, so I'll be bummed if that gets deleted).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Note for future players: deleting your save file will wipe all Pokemon, including any Pokemon you may have gotten from events, Mystery Gifts or other one-time offers. **Be absolutely sure you want to do this before proceeding!**

You can reset your save game from within the Nintendo Switch Settings (i.e. not in-game):

- Open System Settings (from the Nintendo Switch Home Screen)
- Find 'Data Management'
- Scroll down to 'Delete Save Data'
- Choose Pokemon Sword & Shield to delete your save file
- Select the Switch profile you wish to reset

Sources:

- [GamersHeroes.com - How to restart a new game in Pokemon Sword/Shield](http://www.gamersheroes.com/game-guides/how-to-restart-a-new-game-in-pokemon-sword-and-shield/)
- [AttackOfTheFanboy.com - Pokemon Sword and Shield – How to Start a New Game](https://attackofthefanboy.com/guides/pokemon-sword-and-shield-how-to-start-a-new-game/)

Answer (score 7):

In the settings, go to Data Management, and then Delete Save Data. In there, select Pokémon Sword or Shield, and select the user. In this way, only the save game for one user will be deleted.